# Should I use my first SHT on Berneside plains?

Tags: android, guardian-cross

Currently lvl 6 and can't hunt anywhere besides Berneside, I just got a special hunting ticket from the story mode.

I don't plan to spend any money on the game, and from reading it appears that the higher level (and newer?) plains tend to have the better guardians. Of course, the flip side is that my current team is a pitiful group, two 3*s and lower ranked rabble :-) - so adding even 'ok' cards would be a great help.

Is it better to wait for lvl 12 and try hunting in Glaverow (or maybe even save all SHT for much later on), or does spending a few SHT not really matter much in the overall picture?

*As there are significant differences between the two, please note this is for the **Android** version.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you trade.

It is easy to find scam-free trades at http://guardiancross-forum.com or http://gc-forums.com where you can trade 5x 2* guardians or a Silver Slime (a 3* found in all maps) for a 4* to help you get started. If you do this, maximize value by saving your Special Hunting Tickets (SHT) for maps that have brand new or special event guardians.

If you don't trade, it's probably better to use your SHTs early to get 4* guardians that you can be leveling up as you progress.